# How to Display Product Option - BigCommerce

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, bigcommerce

Currently I am using BigCommerce to help maintain a clients site.

A request that I received was to allow the **SKU** or **product.sku** to show within the alert-message that tells the end-user that the product is out-of-stock/unavailable.

Currently the alert-message reads and tells the end-user the **product.title** is out-of-stock but with a store of many SKU's only knowing the **product.title** does not give enough information to the end-user to know specifically which item/color/sku is out-of-stock.

Within my stencil theme I have located where I can change the text via a JavaScript file called Alert.js but using Big Commerce I do not know how to add in a variable that will define a sku based on the product that is in question or being referred.

In the JavaScript file the codes reads as the following:

```
  error(text, dismissable = false){
  this.message(text, 'error', dismissable);
  }
```

I would like for it to read:

```
  error(text, dismissable = false){
  this.message(We are currently out of {{product.sku}}. Please update cart & try again., 
  'error', dismissable);
  }
```

BigCommerce Developers **PLEASE HELP** I know there is a way to inject handlebars within the JS or perhaps inject within the HTML file using a script but I am completely lost and unsure where to start.